# one dropdown appears on the selection of other dropdown using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to create dynamic dropdown of category and on selection of this category sub-category dropdown should appear. I have done this using OOP PHP but really having tought time with codeigniter.

Firstly I have created this category dropdown

```
<?php 
$js =' onChange="callAjaxFunction(this.value)"';
echo form_dropdown('category', $categories, null, $js); ?>
```

Javascript to show sub-category

```
<script>
// JavaScript Document
var enableCache = false;
var jsCache = new Array();
var AjaxObjects = new Array(new sack(),new sack());

function ShowContent(divId,ajaxIndex,url)
{       
    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = AjaxObjects[ajaxIndex].response;
    if(enableCache){
        jsCache[url] =  AjaxObjects[ajaxIndex].response;
    }
    AjaxObjects[ajaxIndex] = false;
 document.getElementById("ajax_container").innerHTML = '';

}

function ShiftChanger(divId,url,id) {
    //to show the div
    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML="";
    if(enableCache && jsCache[url]){
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = jsCache[url];
        return;
    }   
    var ajaxIndex = AjaxObjects.length;

    AjaxObjects[ajaxIndex] = new sack();
    AjaxObjects[ajaxIndex].requestFile = url+"?id="+id;
    document.getElementById("ajax_container").innerHTML = '<img    src=ajax_loader.gif hspace=10 vspace=10 />';     AjaxObjects[ajaxIndex].onCompletion = function(){ ShowContent(divId,ajaxIndex,url+"?id="+id);};
    AjaxObjects[ajaxIndex].runAJAX();
 }

function callAjaxFunction(value)
{   

    ShiftChanger('shiftcontainer','ajax_category.php',value);
 }


  </script>
```

But this is not working. As you can see ajax_category.php is not being able to pass. I think it should be done with controller, I had tried that also but nothing seems as working. I am really stuck with this. Please anyone with little help. Really getting depressed with it :(.

Comment: Can you please copy your callAjaxFunction Javascript method? And by the way why to not use Jquery for this?

Comment: Please do suggest me what to do and how to do in codeignitor??